# php remove the space in the beginning

Tags: php

I am having an array in PHP which contains some line breaks (`\n`) also as the array elements. I am writing these array elements into the CSV file using `fwrite` statement as below.

```
$newLine[] = $row[$i].",";
$newLine[] = "\n";
$csv2 [] = implode(" ", $newLine);
$file1 = fopen("/home/huadong/public_html/ramesh/output_updated.csv","w");
foreach ($csv2 as $line):
$line1 =  ltrim($line);
fwrite($file1, $line1 . PHP_EOL);
endforeach;
fclose($file1);
```

ltrim is not working as it trims only leading white spaces. I have to replace the extra space in the beginning of the CSV file while it is getting written.

The CSV file is getting written as below.

```
Jack 1234
 John 3456
 Jason 3321
```

I am expecting to write into the CSV file as below.

```
   Jack 1234
   John 3456
   Jason 3321
```

Comment: $line1 =  str_replace(' ', '',$line);

Comment: It replaces the spaces inside the array values as well. I just need to replace the first space of the line alone.

Comment: hey have you used fore loop ..You used $i by applying a for loop right ?

Comment: yeah, I have used for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
$newLine[] = $row[$i].",";
$newLine[] = "\n";
$csv2 [] = implode(" ", $newLine);
$file1 = fopen("/home/huadong/public_html/ramesh/output_updated.csv","w");
foreach ($csv2 as $line):
$line1 =  ltrim($line," ");
fwrite($file1, $line1 . PHP_EOL);
endforeach;
fclose($file1);
```

Comment: +1 for using `ltrim`. Mine also works, but i bet yours has the best performance :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) function and a while loop, like this:

```
$name="    Jack 1234";
while(substr($name,0,1)==" ") $name=substr($name,1);
echo $name;//Jack 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

`$line1 =  ltrim($line);`

to this

`$line1 =  ltrim($line," ");`

Comment: That won't work, cause you haven't specified what should be trimmed... This is the correct way to do it: `$line1 = ltrim($line," ");`

Comment: Sure it is.yhanx dude